# "Reply-To" on subject line of email (using php mail)

Tags: php, email, subject

I have set up a simple email for a mailing list using php mail and, using a tutorial I found, I have used boundaries to send it in both plain and html.

Everything is working as it should except the subject line is showing as

**Next Portsmouth Bootstrap meeting Reply-To: mailings@portsmouthbootstrap.org**

I have cannot spot why the "Reply-To" is also showing. I have tried adding \n and \r as well as many other things, but cannot seem to stop this from happening.

I know there are better mailing systems out there, but any light you can shed on this particularly will be greatly appreciated.

```
        $mail_subject="Next Portsmouth Bootstrap meeting\r\n ";
        require("connectdb.php");

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email,name  FROM maillist WHERE subscribed='1'");
        if($sql === FALSE) { echo "err: ".mysqli_error($con); }

        $encoding = "utf-8";
        $subject_preferences = array(
        "input-charset" => $encoding,
        "output-charset" => $encoding,
        "line-length" => 76,
        "line-break-chars" => "\r\n"
);          

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $email = $row['email'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            echo "name=".$name." email=".$email."<br/>";
            $from_name="Portsmouth Bootstrap";
            $from_mail="mailings@portsmouthbootstrap.org";  
            $boundary = uniqid('np');   

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail."> \r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \r\n";
            $headers .= "Date: ".date("r (T)")." \r\n";
            $headers .= iconv_mime_encode("Subject", $mail_subject, $subject_preferences);
            $headers .= "Reply-To: mailings@portsmouthbootstrap.org\r\n";
            $headers .= "Return-Path: mailings@portsmouthbootstrap.org\r\n";
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

            $message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
            $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
            $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
            //Plain text body
            $message .= $allmessageplain;
            $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
            $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
            $unsub = "<p>To unsubscribe from this mailing list please click <a href='https://portsmouthbootstrap.org/unsub.php?email=".$email."'>here</a></p>";
            //Html body
            $message .= $allmessage.$unsub;
            $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

            mail($email, $mail_subject, $message, $headers);
        }
```

Comment: I'd guess that [`iconv_mime_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php) might be at fault with, because that's all I can see. Have a look through the manual, seems to contain notes that stand to be important.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You are right about iconv_mime_encode() being related to the Subject, but reading through the manual, I still cannot see any reason for the Reply-To to be added to this line :/

Comment: You're welcome. Me neither and I have never used that function myself, so I couldn't say what it is exactly that is causing this. Try and remove either the plain text or html mimes; or try a fresh script from the mail manual. Or changing the encoding type. Wish I could help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must append the newline characters after your function call.

```
$headers .= iconv_mime_encode("Subject", $mail_subject, $subject_preferences) . "\r\n";
```

Without the newlines, you are jamming it all on one line, but the two lines need to be separated.

Comment: It seems so obvious now you mention it - every other header is separated. Worked perfectly of course. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to be doing is passing the headers as an array. It saves you the trouble of dealing with all those newlines, which was indeed your original problem.

```
$headers = [
    "MIME-Version"              => "1.0",
    "From"                      => "$from_name <$from_mail>",
    "Content-Type"              => "multipart/alternative;boundary=$boundary",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "8bit",
    "Date"                      => date("r (T)"),
    "Subject"                   => str_replace("Subject: ", "", iconv_mime_encode("Subject", $mail_subject, $subject_preferences)),
    "Reply-To"                  => "mailings@portsmouthbootstrap.org",
    "Return-Path"               => "mailings@portsmouthbootstrap.org",
    "X-Mailer"                  => "PHP/" . phpversion()
];
```

From [the documentation](https://php.net/mail):

> **additional_headers** (optional)
>
> String or array to be inserted at the end of the email header.
>
> ...
>
> If an array is passed, its keys are the header names and its values are the respective header values.

Comment: Good thinking - I will give this ago on my next project!